# Can I include % in the image file name which is used in a web page?

Tags: html, image

I name an image file *100%-satisfaction-guarantee-icon.png* and then put it in my webpage, as below:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/100%-satisfaction-guarantee-icon.png" alt="100% Satisfaction Guarantee" width="124" height="126" />
```

But the image will not show. Can '%' be used in an image file name? And which rules are applied to file names for web pages?

I have also tried to use *%25* for the `%` sign, but it seems not be working.

*https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/themes/datanumen/images/100%25-satisfaction-guarantee-icon.png* still returns the 404 error.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb you should avoid using simbols and ambigious characters in your file names and variable names. I cannot think of a scenario which makes it neccessary to use symbols other than "-" and "_" in your file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply percent-encode the `%` symbol. You can put `%25` instead of `%`

So instead of

```
100%-satisfaction-guarantee-icon.png
```

you could refer to it as

```
100%25-satisfaction-guarantee-icon.png
```

Comment: Thank you. But seems not working. I update my post, the new link with %25 still returns 404 error.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question as asked,  however the percent sign is most likely stripped from the routing in PHP to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Strom, Thank you for your comment. I think what you said is the most possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

A % in a path signifies encoding the URL for the purpose of using special characters (replaces unsafe ASCII characters). I believe this also applies to img tags in HTML.

Check out this wiki link [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or this W3 resource [HTML Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that in the Google Chrome URL bar, if you use space, then it is represented as *%20*. So regret using `%` in your file names while it is a bad practice.

Suggested file name: *100_percentage_satisfaction_guarantee_icon.png*